# Loop will not end. How do i make it exit?

Tags: java, methods, duplicates, switch-statement

Got scolded earlier for not specify the question. Promise to do better this time.

For some reason, the loop doesn't stop when i enter 0, instead it continues to print out the main method again. How do i fix this? I couldn't find out what is wrong with it, since everything else runs smoothly.

Also, I want to use Switch instead of If, but i keep getting Duplicate Variable error. Why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindArea 
{
    // side is only input provided to cube. Area of the cube is returned
    public static double cube (double side)
    {
        double Area;
        return Area = 6 * side * side; 
    }
    // radius is only input provided to sphere. Area of the sphere is returned
    public static double sphere (double radius)
    {
        double Area;
        return Area = 4 * 3.14 * radius * radius; 
    }
    // radius and height are the only inputs provided to cylinder. 
    // Area of the cylinder is returned
    public static double cylinder (double radius, double height)
    {
        double Area;
        return Area = 2 * 3.14 * radius * height + 2 * 3.14 * radius * radius; 
    }
    // outerR and innerR are the only inputs provided to doughnut. 
    // Area of the doughnut is returned
    public static double doughnut (double outerR, double innerR)
    {
        double Area;
        return Area = (2 * 3.14 * innerR) * (2 * 3.14 * outerR);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = 4;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for Cube, 2 for Sphere, 3 for Cylinder, 4 for Doughnut");

        do
        {
            n = input.nextInt();
            if ( n<0 || n>4) {
                System.out.println("Invalid");
            }

            if(n == 1) {
                System.out.print("Enter side measurement of cube: ");
                double side = input.nextDouble();
                double Area = cube(side);   
                System.out.println("The area of the cube is: " + Area);
            }
            if (n == 2) {
                System.out.print("Enter radius measurement of sphere: ");
                double radius = input.nextDouble();
                double Area = sphere (radius);
                System.out.println("The area of the sphere is: " + Area); 
            }
            if (n == 3) {
                System.out.print("Enter radius measurement of cylinder: ");
                double radius = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Enter height measurement of cylinder: ");
                double height = input.nextDouble();
                double Area = cylinder (radius, height);
                System.out.println("The area of the cylinder is: " + Area);
            } 
            if (n == 4) {
                System.out.print("Enter inner radius: ");
                double innerR = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Enter outer radius: ");
                double outerR = input.nextDouble();
                double Area = doughnut (outerR, innerR);
                System.out.println("The area of the donut is: " + Area);
            }
            System.out.println("--------");
            System.out.println("Enter 1 for Cube, 2 for Sphere, 3 for Cylinder, 4 for Doughnut");
            System.out.println("Or enter 0 to exit");
        } while (n != 0);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: it works for me, and no need to write System.exit(1);

Comment: One of the close reasons is "Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the _shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it." Rather than just dumping the code here, you should try and narrow it down to the shortest code that will reproduce the error, find out _exactly_ what isn't working as you'd expect, and ask about that. Yes, it's difficult at first; but this is debugging, and you'll have to learn it at some point. You may find that in narrowing the question, you find out how to answer it!

Comment: @yshavit well i was gonna narrow it down, but then i don't know what exactly is wrong and i afraid you guys might not know what is going on, so i just copied the whole thing

Comment: @KhangLe Well, it's highly unlikely that a `println` is going to change the flow of logic, right? That's a good first step of things to get rid of. Then keep taking stuff out until it no longer reproduces the problem -- and the problem is in something you took out. It can be a bit of an art, but as I said, it's one you're going to have to learn sooner or later. There's no shortcut to learning how to debug.

Comment: @Yshavit I am still new to all of this, that's why. Thank you for the feed back though. I'll try to do better next time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have done this using switch case. Very simple as well

```
public class FindArea {
        // side is only input provided to cube. Area of the cube is returned
        public static double cube(double side) {
            double Area;
            return Area = 6 * side * side;
        }

        // radius is only input provided to sphere. Area of the sphere is returned
        public static double sphere(double radius) {
            double Area;
            return Area = 4 * 3.14 * radius * radius;
        }

        // radius and height are the only inputs provided to cylinder.
        // Area of the cylinder is returned
        public static double cylinder(double radius, double height) {
            double Area;
            return Area = 2 * 3.14 * radius * height + 2 * 3.14 * radius * radius;
        }

        // outerR and innerR are the only inputs provided to doughnut.
        // Area of the doughnut is returned
        public static double doughnut(double outerR, double innerR) {
            double Area;
            return Area = (2 * 3.14 * innerR) * (2 * 3.14 * outerR);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out
                    .println("Enter 1 for Cube, 2 for Sphere, 3 for Cylinder, 4 for Doughnut, Or enter 0 to exit ");



            int n = 0;
            double side = 0;
            double Area = 0;
            double radius = 0;
            double height = 0;

            n = input.nextInt();
            switch (n) {

            case 0:
        System.out.println("Exit");
        System.exit(1);
        break;
            case 1:
                System.out.print("Enter side measurement of cube: ");
                side = input.nextDouble();
                Area = cube(side);
                System.out.println("The area of the cube is: " + Area);
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.print("Enter radius measurement of sphere: ");
                radius = input.nextDouble();
                Area = sphere(radius);
                System.out.println("The area of the sphere is: " + Area);
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.print("Enter radius measurement of cylinder: ");
                radius = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Enter height measurement of cylinder: ");
                height = input.nextDouble();
                Area = cylinder(radius, height);
                System.out.println("The area of the cylinder is: " + Area);
                break;

            case 4:
                System.out.print("Enter inner radius: ");
                double innerR = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Enter outer radius: ");
                double outerR = input.nextDouble();
                Area = doughnut(outerR, innerR);
                System.out.println("The area of the donut is: " + Area);
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("--------");
                System.out.println("Invalid option selected");
                System.out.println("--------");
                System.out
                        .println("Enter 1 for Cube, 2 for Sphere, 3 for Cylinder, 4 for Doughnut");
                System.out.println("Or enter 0 to exit");
                n = input.nextInt();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Good Luck.

Comment: I think there is no sense of reading the nextInt in default case, because it will no longer use.

Comment: @Moni if you dont opt for nextInt in default case then your code will run only if the user enters between 1 to 4 if you enter 5 then it will  stop running. kindly run your code and compare with mine thank you

Comment: I agree with your default case, if user enter other than 1-4 it will show invalid no.but you are again asking for entering the no and read by using nextInt and assigning those value in n variable and than break the case. It means it will come out the switch case, so where are you use this n value.if this switch case is in loop than it will make sense.

Answer (score 2):

It prints the output one more time because the comparison is not made until the end of the Do-While loop.

It checks for all cases of n other than 0, and prints the output no matter what.

I think what you're looking for is more so:

```
n = input.nextInt();
        if(n!=0){
            if ( n<0 || n>4) {
                System.out.println("Invalid");
            }

            if(n == 1) {
                System.out.print("Enter side measurement of cube: ");
                double side = input.nextDouble();
                double Area = cube(side);   
                System.out.println("The area of the cube is: " + Area);
            }
            if (n == 2) {
                System.out.print("Enter radius measurement of sphere: ");
                double radius = input.nextDouble();
                double Area = sphere (radius);
                System.out.println("The area of the sphere is: " + Area); 
            }
            if (n == 3) {
                System.out.print("Enter radius measurement of cylinder: ");
                double radius = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Enter height measurement of cylinder: ");
                double height = input.nextDouble();
                double Area = cylinder (radius, height);
                System.out.println("The area of the cylinder is: " + Area);
            } 
            if (n == 4) {
                System.out.print("Enter inner radius: ");
                double innerR = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Enter outer radius: ");
                double outerR = input.nextDouble();
                double Area = doughnut (outerR, innerR);
                System.out.println("The area of the donut is: " + Area);
            }
            System.out.println("--------");
            System.out.println("Enter 1 for Cube, 2 for Sphere, 3 for Cylinder, 4 for Doughnut");
            System.out.println("Or enter 0 to exit");
        }
```

note the `n!=0`

Additionally look into the use of `switch-case`, once you learn them these comparisons will not only be faster, but very easy to comprehend

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with your switch case -

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = 4;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for Cube, 2 for Sphere, 3 for Cylinder, 4 for Doughnut");
        System.out.println("Or enter 0 to exit");

        n = input.nextInt();
    if ( n<0 || n>4) {
        System.out.println("Invalid");
    }
    else{
        switch(n){
        case 0:{
            System.out.println("You enter 0 to exit");
            break;
        }
        case 1:{
             System.out.print("Enter side measurement of cube: ");
             double side = input.nextDouble();
             double Area = cube(side);   
             System.out.println("The area of the cube is: " + Area);
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            System.out.print("Enter radius measurement of sphere: ");
            double radius = input.nextDouble();
            double Area = sphere (radius);
            System.out.println("The area of the sphere is: " + Area); 
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            System.out.print("Enter radius measurement of cylinder: ");
            double radius = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter height measurement of cylinder: ");
            double height = input.nextDouble();
            double Area = cylinder (radius, height);
            System.out.println("The area of the cylinder is: " + Area);
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            System.out.print("Enter inner radius: ");
            double innerR = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter outer radius: ");
            double outerR = input.nextDouble();
            double Area = doughnut (outerR, innerR);
            System.out.println("The area of the donut is: " + Area);
            break;
        }

        }

    }
```

}